# Js Проверка даты в периоде

Tags: javascript

Есть текущая дата:

```
var date = new Date();
```

и есть переменная периода:

```
var period = "2017-05-05,2017-05-13";
```

Как можно просто проверить находится ли дата в периоде или нет? Может библиотека есть для упрощения этих целей? Сам пытался но не получается с датами у меня( Пока зеленый еще..

Comment: например библиотека [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) c использованием функции [isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/):

```js
var period = "2017-01-01,2017-02-01";
var date = "2017-01-15";

var dates = period.split(",");

var result = moment(date).isBetween(dates[0], dates[1], null, '()');

console.log("The given date is between the dates:", result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Все отлично, но как сделать чтобы дни периода тоже считались?

Comment: чтобы считать включительно последний параметр isBetween сделай '[]'

Comment: @user246535 хмм... подключать целую библиотеку для того, чтобы проверить дату между.....сомнительная полезность

Answer (score 1):

В соседнем ответе предлагают подключить аж целую библиотеку для решения простой задачи. Мне кажется проще сделать нативно:

- Разбить даты на массив.
- Сравнить заданную дату на вхождение в интервал

Как итог:

```js
function checkDateEntrance(date, period) {
  var periods = period.split(',');

  if (date >= new Date(periods[0]) && date <= new Date(periods[1]))
    console.log('УРА!');
  else
    console.log('ЖАЛЬ :(');
}

checkDateEntrance(new Date(), '2017-04-01,2017-05-13');

checkDateEntrance(new Date(), '2017-05-01,2017-05-13');
```

Вроде так.

Comment: в вопросе про библиотеку и спрашивали, так то

Comment: @MikhailM а если в вопросе попросят описать как собрать бомбу, тоже давать описание? Ну бред же. Если ТС очень много работает с датами, с их форматированием, изменением и пр. - имеет смысл. Для одной жалкой обработочки - подключать библиотеку - глупость